# How do I query a child entity for more than one condition using BreezeJS?

Tags: javascript, breeze, durandal

I have a Batch entity that can have many Batch Stations.  I want to get the Batch's that have a Batch Station with the Station Number of 4 and Station Start of null.  I understand I can do something like this:

```
query.where('BatchStations', 'any', 'StationNumber', '==', 4)
```

But how can I check if the Station Start is null as well?  I tried tacking on an and(), but that runs through all the Batch Stations again.  I want to compare these two conditions on the same Batch Station.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a predicate:

```
var pred = Predicate.create("StationNumber", "==", 4)
                       .and("StationStart", "==", null);
var query = new EntityQuery.from(...).where("BatchStations", "any", pred);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

I had to make some sub predicates and "and" them together using breeze.Predicate.and() to create a single predicate.  Here is my solution:

```
var p1 = new breeze.Predicate('StationNumber', '==', 4);
var p2 = new breeze.Predicate('StationStart', '==', null);
var p3 = new breeze.Predicate.and(p1, p2);
var p4 = new breeze.Predicate('BatchStations', 'any', p3);
query = query.where(p4);
```